# Create unique legend for subplot with different columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I have to draw 2 subplots from 2 df that have different columns. I want to get common legend that contains all the columns of the two, similarly to the example below.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({ #without one
    'two' : [-1.,- 2.,- 3., -4.],
    'three' : [4., 3., 2., 1.],
    'four' : [4., 3., 4., 3.]})
tot_1=d1.sum(axis=1)

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
    'two' : [4., 3., 3., 1.],
    'three' : [-1., -1., -3., -4.],
    'four' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})

tot_2=d2.sum(axis=1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

#plot 1
d1.plot.area(stacked=True,legend=False,ax=ax[0])
tot_1.plot(linestyle='-', color='black',legend=False,ax=ax[0])

###SECOND GRAPH####

ax3 = ax[1].twiny()

#plot 2
d2.plot.area(stacked=True,legend=False,ax=ax[1],sharex=ax[0])
tot_2.plot(linestyle='-',color='black',legend=False,ax=ax[1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

The prob is that the columns are not exactly the same in the two dataframes/plots  (same are in both some not)  and should make sure that the legend has all the columns and the colors in the two plots and the legend match.

Even better (but not necessary) would be if I could chose the color for each column, for instance using a dictionary with `col_name:color` to pass

Comment: did you see this answer (the edited one) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31548279/1675954 there's a similar (but different) solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36532501/1675954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use a dictionary of `column-name:color` pairs to colorize the patches and to afterwards create a legend from it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = pd.DataFrame({ #without one
    'two' : [-1.,- 2.,- 3., -4.],
    'three' : [4., 3., 2., 1.],
    'four' : [4., 3., 4., 3.]})
tot_1=d1.sum(axis=1)

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1., 2., 3., 4.],
    'two' : [4., 3., 3., 1.],
    'three' : [-1., -1., -3., -4.],
    'four' : [4., 3., 2., 1.]})
tot_2=d2.sum(axis=1)

columns = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
colors = dict(zip(columns, ["C"+str(i) for i in range(len(columns)) ]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

#plot 1
d1.plot.area(stacked=True,legend=False,ax=ax[0], lw=0,
             color=[colors[i] for i in d1.columns])
tot_1.plot(linestyle='-', color='black',legend=False,ax=ax[0])

###SECOND GRAPH####

ax3 = ax[1].twiny()

#plot 2
d2.plot.area(stacked=True,legend=False,ax=ax[1],sharex=ax[0], lw=0,
             color=[colors[i] for i in d2.columns])
tot_2.plot(linestyle='-',color='black',legend=False,ax=ax[1])

labels = list(set(list(d1.columns) + list(d2.columns)))

handles = [plt.Rectangle((0,0),1,1, color=colors[l]) for l in labels]
ax3.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]